# Has anyone managed to build php5-xapian on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, xapian

As Xapian's been dropped from the Ubuntu repositories, I'm attempting to build my own .deb from the instructions here:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.search.xapian.general/8855

http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/howto-build-your-own-binaries-of-php-xapian-bindings-for-debian/

I can only get things to progress beyond the first few seconds by leaving out 'rm debian/control', but if I do, it looks as if the Python and Ruby bindings are building and passing their versions of smoketest correctly.

However, the PHP part of the build is failing with this error:

```
/home/charlie/xapian-bindings-1.2.8/php/smoketest.php:38: include(xapian.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
FAIL: smoketest.php
```

There's a xapian.php file in /home/charlie/xapian-bindings-1.2.8/php/php5/ but if I copy it to /home/charlie/xapian-bindings-1.2.8/php/ or change the path to it in smoketest.php, the build fails right near the start with:

```
dpkg-source: error: aborting due to unexpected upstream changes
```

Unfortunately I'm out of my comfort zone building from source. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit post James' answer:

Builds fine if I follow instructions exactly. I built it on a test VM initially, but that didn't build the PHP package as PHP itself wasn't installed. Obvious gotcha, but worth mentioning.

Installing generated the following error:

```
Setting up php5-xapian (1.2.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php5.postinst): Permission denied                                                               ssion denied
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
```

It's only a script for restarting Apache. Stopping Apache before running sudo dpkg -i php5-xapian_*.deb prevents the error. Xapian now shows up in phpinfo(). Job done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Debian build system builds in a separate directory to the source files, and that approach currently has a problem with running the PHP bindings smoketest. Until this is fixed properly, you can get things working by running the following commands (adapted from [the Xapian FAQ on PHP bindings for Debian & Ubuntu](http://trac.xapian.org/wiki/FAQ/PHP%20Bindings%20Package), which are based on the information you'd already found):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xapian-bindings
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli devscripts
apt-get source xapian-bindings
cd xapian-bindings-1.2.*
rm -f debian/control debian/*-stamp
env PHP_VERSIONS=5 debian/rules maint
sed -i 's/include_path=php5$/include_path=$(srcdir)\/php5/' php/Makefile.in
dpkg-source --commit
```

At this point you'll be prompted for a patch name (use something like fix-php-buildtests), then dumped in an editor to document the patch, but you don't care about that so you can just save and exit the editor. Then:

```
debuild -e PHP_VERSIONS=5 -us -uc 
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i php5-xapian_*.deb
```

And you're done.

The mailing list thread dealing with this problem hasn't appeared in GMane yet, but [it's available in the Xapian mailman archive](http://lists.xapian.org/pipermail/xapian-discuss/2012-May/008748.html).

Comment: That's great James, thanks. I've got half a dozen 12.04 installs running at the moment. Once they're done, I'll give this a try and post back.

Comment: Added a follow-up to the original post. Thanks for your help.